# Time series to Hankel Matrix

Tags: time-series, pca

This must be bog standard (if so, references would be appreciated):

Suppose I have a (time) series $a_1, a_2, \dotsc, a_n, \dotsc.$
I make an infinite by $k$ Hankel matrix $H(k)$ in the "obvious" way:
$$\begin{align}
&a_1, a_2, \dotsc, a_k\\
&a_2, a_3, \dotsc, a_{k+1}\\
&a_3, a_4, \dotsc, a_{k+2}\\
&\dotsc
\end{align}
$$

What can be said about the singular value decomposition of $H,$ and how is the structure of the time series reflected in this?

Comment: Could you add details about what kind of time series the $a_i$ form? ARMA, ARIMA, etc.? Also out of curiosity, what's the motivation behind this? Does this come out of dynamical systems?

Comment: @AlexR. It  comes from a primitive approach to "Kalman filtering" - predicting the next state of a system based on recent history, where the features are just the previous $k$ observations. If I gave you this dataset without telling you where it came from, it would be natural to try to do PCA on it, and then the question would be "under which circumstances does this do anything"?

Comment: @AlexR. And the series could be anything - part of the question would be whether the structure of the singular values (and possibly vectors) would TELL you if the process was ARM, ARIMA, or whatever.

Comment: This looks useful at least for calculating the singular values: https://ac.els-cdn.com/0024379583900733/1-s2.0-0024379583900733-main.pdf?_tid=e2839028-cf1e-11e7-8968-00000aacb360&acdnat=1511311901_16ae8380c625b5bdada988b71d91ca3c

Comment: @AlexR.Actually, the introduction also gives references to signal processing application of the singular values of the infinite Hankel matrices!

Comment: @IgorRivin perhaps too late, but you may find some great nuggets here: https://www.kaggle.com/jdarcy/introducing-ssa-for-time-series-decomposition

Answer (score 1):

Quite a staggering bit, apparently. I'm just getting into this myself, but you may want to check out the work of Brunton, Kutz and co-workers at the University of Washington, in particular HAVOK analysis (which uses exactly this.) I'm sure a little digging will turn up vastly more.

Here is a YT: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=831Ell3QNck
Presenting this paper: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-00030-8